# Do a whois by reading a the domains from a text file

Tags: text, batch-file, whois

I am trying to do a WHOIS for around 50 domains, i have searched on here and found a script that looks like it works but when i run it, it says:
 "The Maximum setlocal recursion has been reached"
 "The Process can not access the file, it is being used by another process"

Here is the code.

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /F  "tokens=* EOL=# delims=" %%D in (e:\domains.txt) do call :reportit "%%~D"
endlocal
goto :eof

:reportit
setlocal
set "domain=%~1"
echo " Retrieving details for:  %domain%"
echo " WHOIS:       %domain%" >> e:\results.txt
echo "=============================================================" >> e:\results.txt
whois %domain% >> e:\results.txt
timeout 8
endlocal
exit /b
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: the name of the web site is `whois.net`. thi is not a shell command.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use WHOIS as the name of your batch.

Comment: Try http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897435.aspx - it's an extension from Sysinternals - not installed by default. Needs to be installed on your `path`.